# Android how to know if flashlight is on

Tags: android, flashlight

I am using CameraManager and CameraCharacteristics

I would like to know how to check if the flashlight is turned on

Answer (score 3):

Try this bit of code

```
public boolean FlashStatus() {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    return parameters.getFlashMode() == "FLASH_MODE_TORCH";
}
```

Comment: hardware Camera is deprecated. Please follow official documentation for more info
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary