# Android check flash light is on or off

Tags: android, notifications, android-camera, flashlight

I can turn on the flash light by the codes below:

```
cameraId = mCamManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
mCamManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
```

But How could I tell if it's already open. Say if users open the torch by the default Android torch in the notification toolbars, I cannot just set a default flag owned by myself.

Comment: Attempting to open a connection to the camera will fail if another app is already using the torch, as only one app can bind to the hardware at a time.

Comment: pls check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-front-flash-light-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android how to know if flashlight is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38827344/android-how-to-know-if-flashlight-is-on)

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isFlashlightOn() {
        try {
            String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            return cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
                    .get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```